# pos_weight in binary cross entropy calculation

Tags: python, math, pytorch, cross-entropy

When we deal with imbalanced training data (there are more negative samples and less positive samples), usually `pos_weight` parameter will be used.
The expectation of `pos_weight` is that the model will get higher loss when the `positive sample` gets the wrong label than the `negative sample`.
When I use the `binary_cross_entropy_with_logits` function, I found:

```
bce = torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits

pos_weight = torch.FloatTensor([5])
preds_pos_wrong =  torch.FloatTensor([0.5, 1.5])
label_pos = torch.FloatTensor([1, 0])
loss_pos_wrong = bce(preds_pos_wrong, label_pos, pos_weight=pos_weight)

preds_neg_wrong =  torch.FloatTensor([1.5, 0.5])
label_neg = torch.FloatTensor([0, 1])
loss_neg_wrong = bce(preds_neg_wrong, label_neg, pos_weight=pos_weight)
```

However:

```
>>> loss_pos_wrong
tensor(2.0359)

>>> loss_neg_wrong
tensor(2.0359)
```

The losses derived from wrong positive samples and negative samples are the same, so how does `pos_weight` work in the imbalanced data loss calculation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TLDR; both losses are identical because you are computing the same quantity: both inputs are identical, the two batch elements and labels are just switched.**

---

##### Why are you getting the same loss?

I think you got confused in the usage of [`F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits.html) (*you can find a more detailed documentation page with [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss)*). In your case your input shape (*aka* the output of your model) is one-dimensional, which means you only have a single logit `x`, **not two**).

In your example you have

```
preds_pos_wrong = torch.FloatTensor([0.5, 1.5])
label_pos = torch.FloatTensor([1, 0])
```

This means your batch size is `2`, and since by default the function is averaging the losses of the batch elements, you end up with the same result for `BCE(preds_pos_wrong, label_pos)` and `BCE(preds_neg_wrong, label_neg)`. The two elements of your batch are just switched.

You can verify this very easily by not averaging the loss over the batch-elements with the `reduction='none'` option:

```
>>> F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(preds_pos_wrong, label_pos, 
       pos_weight=pos_weight, reduction='none')
tensor([2.3704, 1.7014])

>>> F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(preds_pos_wrong, label_pos, 
       pos_weight=pos_weight, reduction='none')
tensor([1.7014, 2.3704])
```

---

##### Looking into `F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits`:

That being said the formula for the binary cross-entropy is:

```
bce = -[y*log(sigmoid(x)) + (1-y)*log(1- sigmoid(x))]
```

Where `y` (respectively `sigmoid(x)` is for the positive class associated with that logit, and `1 - y` (resp. `1 - sigmoid(x)`) is the negative class.

The documentation could be more precise on the weighting scheme for `pos_weight` (not to be confused with `weight`, which is the weighting of the different logits output). The idea with `pos_weight` as you said, is to weigh the positive term, *not the whole term*.

```
bce = -[w_p*y*log(sigmoid(x)) + (1-y)*log(1- sigmoid(x))]
```

Where `w_p` is the weight for the positive term, to compensate for the positive to negative sample imbalance. In practice, this should be `w_p = #negative/#positive`.

Therefore:

```
>>> w_p = torch.FloatTensor([5])
>>> preds = torch.FloatTensor([0.5, 1.5])
>>> label = torch.FloatTensor([1, 0])
```

With the builtin loss function,

```
>>> F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(preds, label, pos_weight=w_p, reduction='none')
tensor([2.3704, 1.7014])
```

Compared with the manual computation:

```
>>> z = torch.sigmoid(preds)
>>> -(w_p*label*torch.log(z) + (1-label)*torch.log(1-z))
tensor([2.3704, 1.7014])
```