# What is the impact of `pos_weight` argument in `BCEWithLogitsLoss`?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

According to the [pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html?highlight=bce) of `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`, `pos_weight` is an optional argument  a that takes the weight of positive examples. I don't fully understand the statement "pos_weight > 1 increases recall and pos_weight < 1 increases precision" in that page. How do you guys understand this statement?

Answer (score 6):

The binary cross-entropy with logits loss ([`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html), equivalent to [`F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits.html?highlight=bce)) is a sigmoid layer ([`nn.Sigmoid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sigmoid.html?highlight=sigmoid#torch.nn.Sigmoid)) followed with a binary cross-entropy loss ([`nn.BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html?highlight=bceloss#torch.nn.BCELoss)). The general case assumes you are in a multi-label classification task *i.e. a single input can be labeled with multiple classes*. One common sub-case is to have a single class: the binary classification task. If you define `q` as your tensor of predicted classes and `p` the ground-truth `[0,1]` corresponding to the true probabilities for each class.

The explicit formulation for the binary cross-entropy would be:

```
z = torch.sigmoid(q)
loss = -(w_p*p*torch.log(z) + (1-p)*torch.log(1-z))
```

*introducing the `w_p`, the weight associated with the true label for each class*. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68611397/pos-weight-in-binary-cross-entropy-calculation/68769210#68769210) for more details on the weighting scheme used by the `BCELoss`.

For a given class:

```
precision =  TP / (TP + FP)
recall = TP / (TP + FN)
```

Then if `w_p > 1`, it increases the weight on the positive classification (classifying as true). This will tend to increase false positives (**FP**), thus decreasing the *precision*. Similarly if if `w_p < 1`, we are decreasing the weight on the true class which means it will tend to increase false negatives (**FN**), which decreases *recall*.